# How do I remove CHR(0) from strings when using LISTAGG in Oracle DB?

Tags: sql, oracle, null, listagg

I am trying to query an oracle database and get a list of names in a single cell of the result.

I have a query like the following which produces the names in separate rows:

```
SELECT (lastname || ', ' || firstname) as fullname
FROM users
WHERE {some condition}

-- result --    
    fullname
Anderson, Alex
Baker, Bob
Clark, Carl
```

However, when I try and use LISTAGG to concatenate those rows I get the following error:

```
SELECT LISTAGG(fullname, '; ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY fullname) as instructors
FROM
(
    SELECT (lastname || ', ' || firstname) as fullname
    FROM users
    WHERE {some condition}
)

-- desired result --
    instructors
Anderson, Alex; Baker, Bob; Clark, Carl

-- actual result --
Error Type: System.Xml.XmlException
Error Message: hexadecimal value 0x00, is an invalid character. Line 1, position 32.
```

Note that if I use LISTAGG on a string made from concatenating INT values, the query works as expected:

```
SELECT LISTAGG(fullname, '; ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY fullname) as instructors
FROM
(
    SELECT (pk1 || ', ' || pk1) as fullname    -- pk1 is the users primary key
    FROM users
    WHERE {some condition}
)

-- result --
    instructors
01, 01; 02, 02; 03, 03
```

I suspect the problem is that the firstname and lastname fields are null-terminated and LISTAGG is not properly removing the null characters from the result. I'm not sure how I can remove the null characters from the result of the inner query though.

Note that this is a client's database and I am not allowed to modify its contents. I need to be able to read the fields in their current format and produce the desired output.

Comment: What does your setup have to do with XML? What you are showing is not an Oracle error, but a "system.xml" error - what does that mean?

Comment: How are you executing this query? Through a web based front-end that uses XML?  Perhaps try it without using a semi-colon which is used in XML to terminate entities. Also note that integers cannot contain characters such as `&` `<` or `>` which annoy the heck out of xml too.

Comment: @Used_By_already The query is being executed through a custom .net windows forms application. The form takes a text input field and passes it as a SQL query to the database and then places the result into a second textbox. I don't have access to the source code of this application. There is a separate web-based interface that also queries the database I'll see if I can get it to try my custom queries.

Comment: Exactly the point raised by @mathguy : the error being reported is not raised by Oracle, it something bad AFTER the query result has been returned. Something found in strings but not integers. As I suggested before might be things like & < > or apostrophe, quotation marks.

Comment: @Used_By_Already Also to your second point: the semicolon was fine in the 3rd instance where I got the result "01, 01; 02, 02; 03, 03". Just to be sure I tried the actual names with a ':' instead of a ';' and there was no difference.

Comment: Just to be clear: Oracle does not silently add `CHR(0)` on its own initiative. The problem lies elsewhere.

Comment: I'll finish by saying there nothing wrong with your sql syntax and as the error isn't from Oracle I cannot help. I've done all I can. You may need different tags to your question.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Once I'm able to query from the web interface maybe I will be able to see where the actual problem lies.

Comment: @mathguy Believe it or not I fixed the problem by simply using replace to remove chr(0). `SELECT replace((LISTAGG(fullname, '; ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY fullname)), chr(0), '') as instructors` So it seems like my original hunch was correct after all.

Comment: Then the `chr(0)` exist in your `fullname` already. Why didn't that raise an error? You can try this: `select fullname, dump(fullname) from <wherever> where instr(fullname, chr(0)) > 0`. `dump()` will show you the byte stored for each character in `fullname`; look in particular for `0` (which is `chr(0)`).

Comment: @mathguy The dump has revealed some very interesting information! The characters in fullname look to be in a 16bit format as every other byte is a 0. `ABC is 0,65,0,66,0,67` Of course none of these are chr(0) as in 16bits that would be 00. But for some reason LISTAGG reads the string as if it was made of 8bit characters. This is why it suddenly finds chr(0) and throws an xml error. I dumped the working list after the replace, and there is not a single 0 byte, proving the characters are now 8bit instead of 16bit. `ABC is 65,66,67`

Comment: All the characters are in the same character set; REPLACE does not change the character set, and in particular the number of bytes used to represent ASCII letters. The 0's you saw in ABC are actually chr(0). How did you enter ABC though - did you just try `select dump('ABC') from dual`? The values returned by dump are in base 10 by default, but if you want them in hex, you can use the second argument: `dump(<text expression>, 16)` Or `1016` instead of `16` to also get the character set. See https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions048.htm#SQLRF00635

Comment: @mathguy I don't think I explained it properly, I think LISTAGG is changing the string from 16bit characters to 8bit characters. **Before LISTAGG:** I know the 0s in the initial test are not chr(0) because (a) I'm not getting the xml error that is thrown if the result has a chr(0) and (b) these 0 bytes are still there even after I replace chr(0) with nothing. **After LISTAGG:** if no replace is used I get an error because there is a chr(0). With the replace, I see the bytes without any 0s. Now that the string is in 8bit format the replace is searching for an 8bit chr(0) and removes the 0 bytes

Comment: The actual result I got was not ABC it was the actual name from the database, I just wanted to illustrate that the first dump was showing me the byes of the fullname string in decimal, every byte preceded by a 0. And in the second dump the decimal character codes are there but without any 0s.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem. The solution for me was:

```
SELECT replace(LISTAGG(fullname, '; ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY fullname), chr(0)) as instructors
```